# How scroll table to down? LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

I have Table in ScrollPane, I want Scroll down table when add items. When i make that:

```
table.add(...);
scrollPane.setScrollY(table.getHeight());
```

It scrolls on the penultimate element. How fix it?

Comment: Hey, did you managed to solve the problem? If so, can you share answer?

Comment: I put this problem for a while, if I did decide I'll write!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
scrollPane.setScrollPercentY(100);
```

Comment: it is not work, it is wotk as scrollPane.setScrollY(table.getHeight());

Comment: Then the height of the table is not being updated beforehand. Can you call `table.layout()` before calling the setScrollY method, right after adding the element to table?

If this works, let me know so I can update the answer.

Comment: And any luck doing the same for the scrollPane? Can you try putting scrollPane.layout() too? This must work actually.

Comment: It works for me! Used! scrollPane.layout(); scrollPane.setScrollPercentY(100);